# Is Perfect Tense appropriate in "I have forgotten to post your letter."?

Tags: present-perfect

I was supposed to answer the question "Did you post my letter?" I answered "No. I *have forgotten* to." It was a wrong answer. The right one was "No I *forgot* to."

Can I use *Present Perfect* there? On one hand since now I remember that I was supposed to post the letter, absent of this knowledge does not prolong up to now. But on the other hand, there is a consequence of my forgetfulness that is relevant now—the letter is not posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know who told OP that *"No. I have forgotten to"* was a "wrong answer", but it was bad advice.

Since the "forgetting" is still "relevant to the current moment", Present Perfect is grammatically/logically acceptable in such contexts.

But it is true that in practice most native speakers would use Simple Past *"No. I forgot to"*, because very often the actual action described using Present Perfect continues into the present (i.e. - when you say *"I have lived there all my life"*, it ***always*** means you ***still*** live there).

The tricky thing about *forgetting* to do something is that effectively it means you *forgot **about** it*. But as soon as you admit to having forgotten about it *later*, you're *no longer forgetting*. Because it creates a bit of semantic/temporal confusion, natives speakers tend to avoid the implications of Present Perfect here.

Comment: @StoneyB: I was heartened to find 190 hits in Google Books for [I was surprised I had not expected](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+was+surprised+I+had+not+expected%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and only 52 for [I was surprised I did not expect](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+was+surprised+I+did+not+expect%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Not really enough to be "statistically significant", but it agrees with my own gut feel on what people usually say. As to the *reason*, obviously I made that up as I went along. But it's nice to know it strikes a chord.

Comment: ...for completeness, [I **am** surprised I **had not expected**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+am+surprised+I+had+not+expected%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - 3 hits. [I **am** surprised I **did not expect**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+am+surprised+I+did+not+expect%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - 231 hits.

Comment: I would only answer _have forgotten_ to _have you posted_

Comment: @mplungjan: I'm surprised. Per my answer, I certainly don't think Present Perfect is "wrong" in OP's context, but I'd be pretty certain it's very much a minority usage. I'd normally only use it in contexts where I *still* don't remember something (i.e. - if I couldn't recall whether I'd posted the letter or not). But that interpretation is ruled out here by the fact that OP's example features *forgotten **to** [post the letter]*.